# What technique, method or procedure exists for someone to determine a recurring or explicit function that fits a set of data points?

Tags: recurrence-relations, function-and-relation-composition, data-analysis

I have an infinite set of data points (the first seven values are posted bellow) and I'm trying to figure out how someone would go about determining the recurring or explicit function from them?

Currently I'm doing trial and error coupled with intuition, but I was hoping to add a new tool in my arsenal to speed up this process.

This is what I'm working off of so far: $x_{n+1} = f(n)*x_n^2+x_n$ where $x_0=7$

1. 7
2. 9709
3. 222399981598543
4. 24057640120673299065081231814259802792690247621
5. 274062972867247603303734187526423379379849494006252611323711996455451016851117969393277902052213286905663818370054902421548244778428601179153047
6. 3646572857329153158605296568394621924470017894318049552934265727938771350419519323876597313157737363748942547209943434184487880861126705933072740849291891034175500840738617200939947296474649081344684812440520588336208959027878422131506927656554650124238631449858869650561159711902237929404861235877860247350817921461957522126847353780095042869754731945019135999702202667254963467151582448102563440120083035743467524923971430262801031389
7. 77309167478576333877529980854251581250920905836135485371126104911944458534710340062457318209695763600529886628525962133763755121517415658395711871826945946478112029271719754077994428779671926069524322009630684764036240957916863202209758982912808446391489679814846666227609307819286495504801493255058728130313530252771053478004721854018582477744035247046858670745634816203886177789556732690355898435254096055138022537230869417126526886622072965648749048410542372131669205246454543320973439236950630580296581127485958337512742458793730223928979703779951731692032175296637344365346004511177793569981442334461663246456807984335074353952080166387130919914113368173046819122349618403254217919486234588019877154368642540053661371971479093489136029092158625126932664671228108713157227619258490062488262744551918842250715567383669536070454994989620279757542382291807107729387271577577894852779403606574783910068126096330955130237718563791776260641196789388698321260385551752019365890972659446737696668685281430303172538448816621909303073898609792396451186742608568785709355515207426344748504574338784322357530532365680770160605969419094750308109887539881482975279267000252155446168203414731613126346091036613940175302597885534853129498681064403722935068287844448460093608851852809646530218168138639377570142076037654771103

Comment: What is $f(x)$ ? is it  special function ?

Comment: Its my unknown currently. I know it produces an integer but I'm not sure of its structure. My current assumption is that solving for the structure of f(x) will give me my complete recursive function. Note: the function marked above is the current state of my 'guess' as to what the true structure of the function would be.

Comment: @Bulbasaur Sorry, no it is not a special function. It just uses $x_n$ and outputs an integer value.

Comment: Is your list the value of successive $x$’s? If so, this doesn’t seem as pertinent as the values of $f(x)$ which are implicit in the list. For instance, it seems that $f(7)=198.$

Comment: Yes this list is successive. I used $f(x_n)$ because $x_{n+1} = ax_n^2+x_n$ would inaccurate since `a` is not a constant but varies similarly in proportion to n.

Comment: @Semiclassical would it be better for me to write $f(n)$ instead of $f(x_n)$?

Comment: Maybe. It can’t really hurt. That said, the values of $f(n)$ seem to grow very fast…

Comment: @Semiclassical That is why I'm asking as to how someone would tackle this, it would be nice if someone solved it, but I would rather learn how to do this in the future. (Teach vs Give a man a fish)

Comment: @Tolure what is $y$ and $x$ in your comment. Is that $y=f(x_n)$ and $x=x_n$?

Comment: @AHusain it was a function that I calculated from a different  recursive function using information I had found here.  https://www2.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/gfology2.pdf

Comment: @Tolure That seems to match [OEIS-A152007](https://oeis.org/A152007), though it's not clear why you'd expect it to have any "nice" associated recurrence.

Comment: @dxiv I was hoping to get a technique or procedure so that in the future I would know how to map other data to a recurring or explicit function. Thank you for the link, I'll have a lot of fun scouring this site.

Comment: @dxiv I'm sad that there isn't a "nice" associated recurrence but as an arm chair mathematician I'm very happy to see that someone else came up with this sequence while analyzing the Collatz Conjecture. I'm excited to read over their paper.

Comment: @Tolure There is no general "recipe" to derive a recursion. If you have an expression for $x_n=f(n)$ you can try to eliminate $n$ between a few consecutive relations and, if that works, you get a recurrence for $x_n$. Note however that recurrence relations need not be unique, for example $\,x_n=2^n+n\,$ satisfies both $\,x_{n+1} = 2 x_{n} - n + 1\,$ and $\,x_{n+1} = 3 x_n- 2 x_{n-1} - 1\,$.